# Switching between Forms in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

How to switch between forms in winforms ?

I tried below code:

```
this.hide();
   Form1 f = new Form1();
   f.Show();
```

Here the result was not as expected, the new panel displayed with different location from parent panel. Any ways to make the navigation perfect ?

Comment: sooo...set the location prior to showing?!?!

Comment: f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual; f.Location = this.Location;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CenterParent` flag, providing your parent window in `Show` function.

```
var frm = new Form2();
frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
frm.Show(this);
```